# Update a table when the view has been modified by using a trigger

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, triggers, code-first

I have a database in a server as [test]. This [test] database has about fifty tables and I have created a view in that [test] database by using most essential table columns. Then again there's another database in the same server as [list] and I have created a view in the [list] database by referring to the [test] database view. Then I inserted the data in the view of the [list] database to a table in the same [list] database. I need to update my both view and table in the [list] database once the [test] database has been updated.

To do that first I have written a trigger to update the view in the [list] database and it worked. This is the trigger.

```
Use database list
Create trigger UpdateView on listView Instead of Update
AS
Begin
Update [test].[dbo].[testView]
set testPersonId = testPersonId + 1
From testView
End
Go
```

Now I need to update my [list] database table once the listView has updated. To do that I have written the following trigger. When I executed the trigger, I got the result of commands completed successfully, but didn't update my table.

```
Use database list
Create trigger UpdateTable on listTable Instead of Update
AS
Begin
Update [list].[dbo].[listView]
set listPersonId = listPersonId + 1
From listView
End
Go
```

I just need to know the wrong of this trigger and how to make it work.

Here are the object in my testView.

```
> testPersonId int
> testPersonName nvarchar
> testDepId int
> testDepName nvarchar
> testLogRecordNowId int
> testLogRecordNowTime datetime
> testNowLogEvent smallint
> testLastLogRecordTime datetime
> testLastLogEvent smallint
> testInTimeHour nvarchar
> testInTimeMinute nvarchar
```

Here are the objects in my listView.

```
> listPersonId int
> listPersonName nvarchar
> listDepId int
> listDepName nvarchar
> listLogRecordNowId int
> listLogRecordNowTime datetime
> listNowLogEvent smallint
> listLastLogRecordTime datetime
> listLastLogEvent smallint
> listInTimeHour nvarchar
> listInTimeMinute nvarchar
```

Then my table in the [list] database has created by the codefirst manner. Here's the code.

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonLogId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PersonId{ get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(32)]
        public string PersonName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int DepId { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(64)]
        public string DepName { get; set; }

        public int LogRecordNowId { get; set; }

        public DateTime LogRecordNowTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int16 LogEventNow { get; set; }

        public DateTime LogRecordLastTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int16 LogEventLast { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(33)]
        public string InTimeHour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int InTimeMinuteMinute { get; set; }
```

I was able to insert the listView data to this table(listTable). Now I just need to update this table once the listView is updating. Is it possible to do that with triggers? If it is not, is there another way to do that without using triggers?

Comment: Your code looks likes you are updating the view, and not the table, but then you didn't tell us your object names, so I'm just guessing, which is all anyone can do with the little information you've provided.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Please check it now.

Comment: I don't think this is a SQL Server issue at all.   When you said you were updating a `VIEW` I thought you meant the SQL Server object, but it appears you mean a .net object.  I don't know what "codefirst manner" is, but I am sure it is not a pure SQL-Server concept.  It's less clear to me than before exactly what objects you have on your SQL Server.

Comment: I don't think this is related to your current problem, but any time I see a SQL Server trigger that doesn't reference either [inserted or deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), alarm bells start going off - your triggers are currently completely ignorant of *what* has changed in the table/view.